# How can I start a Python program in a scrollable, resizable command window (in Windows)

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I start a Python script from a scheduled task in Windows Server 2008r2.
The script only generates text output going to STDOUT.
The CMD file first checks to see if the script is already running, and if not, runs this command:

```
start "Title Text for Window" python mypythonscript.py
```

This results in the script running in a fixed size terminal window. It cannot be interactively resized, and there are no scroll bars or ability to scroll back.

How can I cause the script to run in the same type of window I would get if I ran CMD.EXE and typed `python mypythonscript.py`?
I know I can change the window size from within Python, but I'd like it to behave like it was launched from an interactive CMD window.

Comment: Have you read the output of the `START /?` command? What does `NEWWINDOW` do?

Comment: I've added the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, because a 'CMD file' is a batch file. If that batch file is running as a scheduled task, you should be aware that it will very likely use a different working directory. Therefore if you're going to use the `Start` command, it would be safer to define that working directory, using its `/D` option, _(probably assigned to the location holding your `.py` file)_. I would also advise that you are not lazy with your command, and use `"F:\ull\PathTo\python.exe"`, this means it does not have to rely upon searching both `%Path%`, and `%PathExt%`.

Comment: @lit - START /? does not mention a NEWWINDOW option. Neither does https://ss64.com/nt/start.html, although it mentions /B will start _without_ creating a new window.

Comment: @Compo - Yes, I have full path to python and the python source in the actual script. I was just keeping simple because I thought the paths were not relevant.  Does the working directory affect the behavior of the window in terms of scroll bars or resize ability?

Comment: @tim11g, NEWWINDOW is on my system. Here is a 2018 article talking about it. https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-build-17682-pc-and-earlier-everything-you-need-know

Answer (score 0):

The following command should work the way you want:

```
start "Window Title" cmd /k python mypythonscript.py
```

Using `cmd /k` opens up a regular `cmd.exe` window that remains even after the command it's running (i.e., `python mypythonscript.py`) has completed. This windows should be dynamically resizable.

Comment: Adding the CMD /K doesn't change the behavior, other than retaining the window after completion as you mention.  The window is still not resizable.